# How to disable all days from jquery ui calendar EXCEPT the mondays of every week?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want the user to be able to see all days from within the month, but to be able to select only the mondays of every week. I know that this is done on "beforeshowday" or something like that, but I don't know how. Any help, please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2Ekc6/)</kbd>

You can use the [`beforeShowDate event`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) of the datepicker combined with [`Date.getDay()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) to do what you want, like this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(arr.indexOf(day) == -1)];
    }
});
```

---

Update Better Use

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2Ekc6/2)</kbd>

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 0)];
    }
});
```